# Postresql using subquery select in order by clause

Tags: postgresql, subquery, order-by

Is it possible to order by a selected columnname?

```
  SELECT * FROM tablex ORDER BY  quote_ident((
  select column_name from information_schema.columns
  where table_name = tablex AND column_name LIKE 'Index')) ASC;
```

The output of this is not ordered according to the columnname Index.

So basically my question is if i can use a select query in the order by clause like this simple one:

```
SELECT * FROM tablex ORDER BY (SELECT Index FROM table WHERE....);
```

What did i oversee?

Comment: No, that's not possible - at least not with plain SQL

Comment: How can I implement it then? Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: `... select column_name ... where column_name LIKE 'Index'` - are you serious?

Comment: was just a test i want to search for LIKE 'Index_18%' something like this